# What desktop software (for Mac OS) is there similar to Zite?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, rss

[Zite](http://zite.com/) is an awesome iPad app that offers a personalized magazine from web sources (an amazing variety of public RSS feeds from conventional news to popular blogs). You start by giving it some keywords that characterize your interests. Then, every time you read an item, you can indicate whether you like it or not, and it will learn your tastes and give you more suitable content.

I love it, but I don't have my iPad anymore. What similar applications exist for the Mac desktop, or as a web app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have found something by now (if so please share), but I just discovered Prismatic, which is similar to Zite, but on the web, and mobile. http://getprismatic.com/.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/prismatic-perfect-desktop-alternative-flipboard-zite/

Comment: That prismatic link seems to go to a different company now

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pulp from Acrylic software](http://www.acrylicapps.com/pulp/mac/). It has many of the same features as Zite. The product description from their website:

> News shouldn't be like email. Pulp takes your favorite news feeds and presents them in a beautifully friendly & familiar format, making it easy to quickly scan through headlines, previews, and photos to find the stories that interest you most. It's like your very own personalized newspaper, designed for your Mac & iPad.

Comment: I don't want to have select news feeds, but to discover new contents from new sources, based on keywords and my feedback on the stories presented to me…